# Дискорд бот не работает на компьютере

Tags: c#, discord

Не понимаю в чем проблема, подскажите пожалуйста. Бот работает на VPS сервере и отвечает на SocketSlashCommand, но вот на компе я получаю "Приложение не отвечает", а в консоль ошибка

```
Gateway     A SlashCommandExecuted handler has thrown an unhandled exception.:
System.TimeoutException: Cannot respond to an interaction after 3 seconds!
at Discord.WebSocket.SocketCommandBase.RespondAsync(String text, Embed[] embeds, Boolean
   isTTS, Boolean ephemeral, AllowedMentions allowedMentions, MessageComponent components,
   Embed embed, RequestOptions options)
at InfoFunction(SocketSlashCommand command) in \Program.cs:line 171
at SlashCommandHandler(SocketSlashCommand command) in Program.cs:line 106
at Discord.EventExtensions.InvokeAsync[T](AsyncEvent`1 eventHandler, T arg)
at Discord.WebSocket.DiscordSocketClient.TimeoutWrap(String name, Func`1 action)
```

На этих линиях, к примеру, 171, расположен такой код

```
var errorEmbed = new EmbedBuilder().WithDescription($"**{command.Data.Options.First().Value}** не найден").WithColor(Color.Red);
await command.RespondAsync(embed: errorEmbed.Build());
```

Самое интересное то, что загруженный бот на VPS отвечает без ошибок. :(

Comment: Интерактивные команды тесно связаны с временем локального компьютера, если оно отстает хоть на секунду, будет выдавать это сообщение, ибо сам дискорд требует обратного ответа в течении 3 секунд. Собственно, проверяйте часы компьютера, синхронизируйте. Ну и да, от это сказано [в документации](https://discordnet.dev/faq/int_framework/general.html#im-getting-systemtimeoutexception-cannot-respond-to-an-interaction-after-3-seconds), которую первым делом надо читать, а не спрашивать у незнакомых людей и ждать часами ответа.

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка заключается в том, что максимальная задержка ответа слэш-команды в Discord - `3 секунды`.

Вам необходимо сделать так, чтобы ответ поступил в течении `3 секунд` или `задержать ответ`. Пример Вы можете найти [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1478448/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-discord-py-py-cord/1478599#1478599).